# Terminology regarding uniform convergence of doubly indexed sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose you have a double sequence $\{ f_m(n) \}_{n,m \in \mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers with the property that:
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \ \ \exists N=N(\epsilon),M=M(N) \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{ such that } n \geq N,m \geq M \implies |f_m(n)| < \epsilon.$$
This is not as good as uniform convergence (where we can forget about the value of $n$ in taking $\lim_{m \to \infty} f_m(n)$) but not as bad as point-wise convergence (where we can't assume the inequality holds for all $n \geq N$).

I have been using phrases like "ultimately uniformly convergent", because at some point $N(\epsilon)$ and beyond one can forget about the value of $n$, but is there already a term for this that I should be using?

Thank you very much!